# How to align width of a table header column and the table body column?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table with the following requirements in `HTML`:

- It should be possible to scroll (vertical and horizontal)
- It should have fixed header columns
- It shouldn't have word-wrap
- Width of all the columns should be adoptive (aligned to the left side of the content)
- In case if the table has width less than 100%, the last column should be stretched to the right.
- Header columns should have same width as according to data columns

According to this requirement I've created table, also I did first 5 requirements except the last one.

My example:

```css
.TableViewer table
{
   width:           100%;
   table-layout:    fixed;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
.TableViewer table tbody
{
   display:  block;
   width:    100%;
   overflow: auto;
   height:   400px;
}
.TableViewer table thead tr
{
   display: block;
}
.TableViewer table thead
{
   background: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
.TableViewer table th
{
   padding:     0 5px;
   text-align:  center;
   font-family: monospace;
   white-space: nowrap;
   border:      1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
.TableViewer table td
{
   padding:     0 5px;
   text-align:  left;
   font-family: monospace;
   white-space: nowrap;
   border:      1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
.TableViewer table td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="TableViewer">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr><th>index</th><th>time</th><th>data</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Summary: How to stretch `thead` columns width according to the `tbody` column width? (in provided solution borders)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey..been a year you asked the question, by any chance you got the solution to the problem, you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove display block.

```css
.TableViewer table
{
   width:           100%;
   table-layout:    fixed;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
.TableViewer table tbody
{
   width:    100%;
   overflow: auto;
   height:   400px;
}
.TableViewer table thead
{
   background: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
.TableViewer table th
{
   padding:     0 5px;
   text-align:  center;
   font-family: monospace;
   white-space: nowrap;
   border:      1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
.TableViewer table td
{
   padding:     0 5px;
   text-align:  left;
   font-family: monospace;
   white-space: nowrap;
   border:      1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
.TableViewer table td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="TableViewer">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr><th>index</th><th>time</th><th>data</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
         <tr><td>nnnnnn</td><td>hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy </td><td>[some data]</td></tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, if I remove `display: block;`, the width of ALL columns will be stretched.

_Requiremets: 1,Width of all columns should be adoptive (align to the left side of the content) 2.In case if the table has a width less than 100%, the last column should be stretched to the right._